# Wann ist "Berufs-" und wann "beruflich" zu verwenden?

Tags: adjective, noun

Wie kann man erkennen, ohne in einem Wörterbuch zu checken, ob es z.B. berufliche Erfahrung oder Berufserfahrung heißt?

Das gleiche gilt für:

- Dreh- vs. drehbar
- Industrie- vs. industriell
- Allein- vs. alleinig
- Seiten- vs. seitlich

uvm.

Comment: _Wie kann man erkennen, ohne in einem Wörterbuch zu checken ..._ Man lernt es und erinnert sich an das Gelernte.

Comment: Super hilfreich! Endlich, die Lösung aller Probleme.

Comment: @infinitezero Na ja, das ist das Gleiche wie mit unregelmässigen Verben. Es gibt halt keine feste Regel dafür.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meines Erachtens kann man das gar nicht checken, ohne sich in einem Wörterbuch (durch Googeln o.ä.) über den Gebrauch zu informieren. Wenn das zusammengesetzte Wort (mit einer passenden Definition!) im Wörterbuch zu finden ist, spricht das dafür, dieses auch zu benutzen.

In den meisten Fällen ist es egal: Ob ich *Berufsrisiko* oder *berufliches Risiko* sage, *Industrieabfälle* oder *industrielle Abfälle*, *Seitenabstand* oder *seitlicher Abstand*, beide Varianten sind zulässig.

Nur wenn ein Ausdruck im jeweiligen Umfeld so verbreitet verwendet wird, dass die andere Variante "sonderbar" wirkt, sollte man auf diese verzichten. Um das zu wissen, muss man das Wort aber bereits kennen oder sich informieren.

Die *Seitenlinie* beim Fußball würde ich zum Beispiel nicht als "seitliche Linie" bezeichnen.
Es gibt kein "alleiniges Stellungsmerkmal" sondern nur ein *Alleinstellungsmerkmal* (zusätzlich: *alleinig* bezieht sich auf *Stellung* und nicht auf *Merkmal*!).

Comment: Sehe ich auch so. Während **Drehstuhl** ein bekanntes Wort ist, ist ein **drehbarer Stuhl** nicht unbedingt das gleiche. Mehr als die Erfahrung bleibt hier nicht.